# Scrolling the whole screen on GridView's scroll

Tags: android

I have a fragment and below this fragment a container which (sometimes) contains a GridWiew. How can I scroll the whole screen on GridView’s scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you will have to add scrollView as a parent which will be parent to both the fragment and gridView. In that scenario scrolling content based on gridview is not a desirable solution as it will result in 2 scroll . Instead you will have to disable scrolling of gridview and add height to gridview.This would though remove the recycling feature.

GridView of fixed height

```
package com.mytestapp
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.content.Context;
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

    ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ScrollView should be the root of the hierarchy if you want the children to get scrolled.